# PyQGIS: QgsRasterFileWriter generates blank (all zeros) raster when used in standalone script

Tags: python, raster, pyqgis, export, pyqgis-3

QGIS version: 3.16.15
Python version: 3.9

I am trying to export some raster from a WMS-sourced background raster layer. For doing so, I am delimiting the export area to be exported by using a vector layer grid. Then, I generate a .tif file by using `QgsRasterFileWriter`.

This works like a charm when I execute the code from the QGIS embedded Python console. However, when I replicate the process from a standalone script, with the necessary library imports and `QgsApplication` `initQgis()` beforehand, it still works with no error message and generates the output raster files, but those are blank. The size of the output files with the standalone code is the same as the one of those generated from the QGIS-embedded code and they are geo-located where they should, but the STATISTICS for the different Bands show that all values are set to 0 (see images below).

The issue is the same if the base raster does not come from a WMS source. For example, if I try to clip small rectangles from a large raster I have the same result. So I think it is related to an issue with `QgsRasterFileWriter`.

The code and some raster examples below.

```py
import sys,os
QGIS_BASE="C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16.15"
sys.path.append(os.path.join(QGIS_BASE,"apps\qgis-ltr\python"))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(QGIS_BASE,"apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins"))

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *



QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(QGIS_BASE, False)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

#after this point, same code as in Qgis where it works alright
#***********************************************************************

my_dir =r'path\folder'  

my_grid = QgsVectorLayer(r'vectorlayerpath\test_area.shp', 'test_area', 'ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(my_grid)
XYZ_tiles_URL='format&type=xyz&url=http://wmsurl/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&zmax=18&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857'
my_base_layer = QgsRasterLayer(XYZ_tiles_URL, 'Base raster layer', 'wms')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(my_base_layer)

##pixel dimensions in meters (EPSG:3857)
my_pixel_width = 5
my_pixel_height = 5

# provider
my_provider = my_base_layer.dataProvider()
# renderer
my_renderer = my_base_layer.renderer()
# crs (EPSG:3857)
my_crs = my_grid.crs()

my_pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
my_pipe.set(my_provider.clone())
my_pipe.set(my_renderer.clone())

# iterate over each feature (rectangles) in my_grid layer
for my_area in my_grid.getFeatures():

    # distances in meters (EPSG:3857)
    my_ncols = (my_area['right'] - my_area['left']) / my_pixel_width
    my_nrows = (my_area['top'] - my_area['bottom']) / my_pixel_height

    my_rectangle = my_area.geometry().boundingBox()

    my_RGB_raster_file = 'AB' + str(int(my_area['id'])) + '_rasterRGB_TEST.tif'
    raster_path = my_dir + '/' + my_RGB_raster_file

    print(raster_path)
    file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(raster_path)
    file_writer.Mode(0)

    file_writer.writeRaster(my_pipe,
                            my_ncols,
                            my_nrows,
                            my_rectangle,
                            my_crs,
                            QgsProject.instance().transformContext(),
                            None)
```

[image: Size of the .tif files is the same]

[image: Raster files generated from QGIS GUI are alright]

[image: Statistics of files generated from standalone script are set to 0, resulting in blank files]

Comment: Have you tried your code under QGIS without the 2 `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(...)` ? Because in standalone script, you specified `qgs = QgsApplication([], False)`, and `False` for no GUI. Maybe it's related to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately yes, it's the same without those two lines.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear : have you tried under QGIS your script without the two lines ?

Comment: Yes, in Qgis it works alright. The problem is that I need to run this outside Qgis, from a standalone script in pycharm or similar.